# Regex - Python: Replace "." by ".\n" unless [0-9]{0,2} before "."

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to replace all punctuation marks "." in a string with a line-break unless the full stop is preceded by a number.

My code is:

```
    response1 = re.sub(r'\. ',
        r'.\n',
        response1)
```

But I don't know how to make it work. I've tried some solutions to negate a Regex found on the internet, but I have no idea what I'm doing.

```
^((?![0-9]{0,}\. ))$
```

Input:

```
Lorem ipsum. 1. dolor sit amet Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 2. Ut enim ad minim veniam Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum. 
1. dolor sit amet Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
2. Ut enim ad minim veniam Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.
```

The ideal output would be (note: the capital after the "[0-9]{0,1} (.*)". Exp "Consectetur"):

```
Lorem ipsum. 
1. dolor sit amet 
Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
2. Ut enim ad minim veniam 
Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.
```

Thank you,

Comment: Any negative lookaround for a token of (possibly) length 0 will be fulfilled... It looks like you're trying to add linebreaks before capital letters, but your attempted patterns and question don't say anything about that?

Comment: My question is about adding linebreaks if the full stop doesn't have a number before, but it would be appreciated if I can have help for the capital letter too. I was unable to make my main issue works so I didn't dig further to work on the capital pattern. I'm not really good with Regex. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to check to see if there's *at least one* number before the `.`, not if there are `{0,2}` numbers before the dot. (Negative lookaround for anything repeated *0* times will always be fulfilled, after all)

Start with negative lookbehind for a digit before the `.` with

```
(?<![0-9])\. *
```

(make sure to match the trailing space, if any, so they can be replaced)

and replace with a newline and the dot

```
.\n
```

To also replace the position behind capital letters with a newline, you can alternate, and use

```
(?<![0-9])(\.) *|(?<![0-9]\. )(?!^)(?=[A-Z])
```

- `(?<![0-9]\. )` - Make sure this position isn't right after a `##.`
- `(?!^)` - Make sure this position isn't at the start of the string
- `(?=[A-Z])` - Lookahead for a capital letter

and replace with

```
\1\n
```

https://regex101.com/r/0cqH3L/2/